# Storing array of double in sql database

Tags: sql, arrays, string, web-applications, blazor-client-side

I have model that needs to store measurements (double values) in an array of up to max size about 10. 
I will **always** save and retrieve the whole array, and thus no indexing on the array is needed when saving or fetching. All that is needed is a `DateTime`and an ID for the measurement place.
My first attempt, without much thinking was to save the array as a varbinary. BUT, since it will be used in a webapp (Blazor wasm), I guess there will already be a conversion to a (json) string when sending the values over http Get/Post - so I thought why not keep it as a string all the way until I need the actual value in the webapp (i.e. in my custom HttpService/MeasurementRepository).
That is:

```
namespace ModelNamespace
{
    public class MeasurementS
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(60)] // maximum of 10 values in array with one decimal and max value of 999.9 (5 digits + one ',' separator = 6*10-1)
        public string Values { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class MeasurementN
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
        public double[] Values { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public static class MeasurementNSConverter
    {
        private static readonly char del = ',';

        public static MeasurementN ConvertFromStringToNumber(MeasurementS m)
        {
            return new MeasurementN()
            {
                DateTime = m.DateTime,
                Id = m.Id,
                SiteID = m.SiteID,
                Values = StringToDoubleArray(m.Values)
            };
        }

        public static MeasurementS ConvertFromNumberToString(MeasurementN m)
        {
            return new MeasurementS()
            {
                DateTime = m.DateTime,
                Id = m.Id,
                SiteID = m.SiteID,
                Values = string.Join(del, m.Values.Select(v=> v.ToString("F1")))
            };
        }

        private static double[] StringToDoubleArray(string s)
        {
            var parts = s.Split(del);
            var n = parts.Length;
            var result = new double[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToDouble(parts[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the webapp (front end) perform the conversion from the MeasurementS (-tring) to MeasurementN (-umerical) and and back.

I wonder if anyone can see any major drawbacks or if there are smarter ways of doing this? I have read about issues with storing values as strings (which i guess varbinary is equally sensitive to).

Edit: debugging locally I run sql server and then azure sql when published.

Comment: What is your Database? MySQL or SQL Server or what? If it is SQL Server, and is >= 2016 version, you can use the JSON data type.
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/01/17/query-json.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Srinika Pinnaduwage